# c++ opengl: sleep() does not affect glutPostRedisplay() during an animation

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opengl

I have a sphere drawn on the screen.  When I press a button I want the sphere to slowly move to the right.  I am trying to accomplish this with

```
for (int i = 0;i<10;i++)
{
sphere.moveToRight(0.1);
glutPostRedisplay();
sleep(1000);
}
```

But instead of animated, it waits a few seconds and then draws the sphere in the final location.  I assume it is because sleep is stopping the glutPostRediplay().  Any ideas of how to accomplish this basic annimation?

Comment: Try to switch position of the `glutPostRedisplay` and `Sleep` calls

Comment: Ya i tried that, no luck

Comment: And the above code is called in your `glutIdleFunc`?

Comment: It is called by my glutKeyboardFunc method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `glutPostRedisplay` wrong.

Check out: http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node20.html

> `glutPostRedisplay` marks the normal plane of current window as needing
>   to be redisplayed. `glutPostWindowRedisplay` works the specified window
>   as needing to be redisplayed. After either call, the next iteration
>   through `glutMainLoop`, the window's display callback will be called to
>   redisplay the window's normal plane. Multiple calls to
>   `glutPostRedisplay` before the next display callback opportunity
>   generates only a single redisplay callback. `glutPostRedisplay` may be
>   called within a window's display or overlay display callback to
>   re-mark that window for redisplay.

Which means, after 10 seconds your image will get refreshed once.

Comment: Perfect explanation! glutSwapBuffers still didnt do the trick, however I used to explanation and now I am just calling display().  It is working now

Comment: Sure it only works with double buffered rendering... 
`glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH)`
When you have `GLUT_DOUBLE` set, `glutSwapBuffers` should work.

Comment: @KoKuToru: glutSwapBuffers should not be called in a inner loop, but only at the end of the rendering to make the rendered picture visible. The proper way to animate things in a GLUT programm is to take a timing beween calls of the display function and issue a glutPostRedisplay in the GLUT idle function (or just use glutPostRedisplay as idle itself).

Comment: @datenwolf haven't wrote with glut for years. 
I thought `glutSwapBuffers` is the same as `glXSwapBuffers`

Comment: @KoKuToru: Indeed it is the same. But GLUT expects display to return eventually (preferrably right after glutSwapBuffers has been called) so that input events can be processed. After all pending events have been processed the idle function is called. Just keeping the display function in a loop with swapping buffers at the end will play some animation, but it will prevent the program from processing events.