# Pausing in OpenGL successively

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-c++, sleep

```
void keyPress(unsigned char key,int x,int y){
    int i;
    switch(key){
    case 'f':
        i = 3;
        while(i--){
            x_pos += 3;
            sleep(100);
            glutPostRedisplay();
        }
    }
}
```

- Above is the code snippet written in C++ using GLUT library in Windows 7.
- This function takes a character key and mouse co-ordinates x,y and performs translation along x-direction in 3 successive steps on pressing f character. Between each step the program should sleep for 100 ms.
- We want to move a robot, and pause successively when he moves forward steps.
- We are facing a problem in making the program sleep between the 3 steps. What is the problem in the above code snippet?

Comment: "We are facing a problem in making the program sleep" What happens and what would you expect to happen?

Comment: we expect to translate a robot and sleep for 100ms and move it again and sleep again. Successive sleeps are not working. Only one sleep works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** The answer of jozxyqk seems better to me. This answer solves the problem in a dirty way.

---

You are misusing `glutPostRedisplay`, as is stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8479379/1907026). The problem being, that `glutPostRedisplay` marks the current window as needing to be redisplayed, but it will only be done once you get in the `glutMainLoop` again. That does happen only once, hence only one sleep seems to work.

In fact all three sleeps work, but you get only one redraw after 300 ms.

To solve this, you have to find another way of redrawing the scene.

```
while(i--){
    x_pos += 3;
    sleep(100);
    yourDrawFunction();
}
```

---

*Assuming that you are working on a UNIX system.*

> sleep for 100 ms

```
sleep(100);
```

The problem here is, that you are sleeping for 100 seconds, as you are probably using the sleep function of the `<unistd.h>` header, which defines `sleep()` as:

```
extern unsigned int sleep (unsigned int __seconds);
```

What you want is probably something like

```
usleep(100000); //sleeps for 100000 microseconds == 100 ms
```

Comment: This answer pertains to Windows, too. `sleep` is not `Sleep`.

Comment: Adding another loop or entry point for drawing goes against standard rendering loop practice. It may work, but it's a hack. E.g. you lose event handling during this sleep and some gl frameworks such as webgl don't provide an explicit swap buffers.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the issue with your code is your sleep is messing with glut's main loop. The call stack might look something like this

```
main() -> glutMainLoop() -> keyPress() -> sleep()

#but can't get to this...
main() -> glutMainLoop() -> display()
```

Until `keyPress()` returns, glut's main loop cannot continue to render the next frame. It's waiting for the function to return. **All `glutPostRedisplay()` does is say "*hey, something's changed so the image is stale and we need to redraw the next time the main loop iterates*"**. It doesn't actually call `display()`.

You'll have to structure your code such that the main loop can continue as normal, but still include a delay between drawing. For example:

- In `keyPress()`, set a `moving = true` state. Let the function return.
- In the `idle()` function, call `sleep()` if moving or maybe if you *have* moved last time (really you might want to look into calculating elapsed time and do the timing yourself so you don't block the entire program)
- Again in `idle()` increase `x_pos` and decrease your move count, let the function return, glut will draw, then call idle again and you can sleep/move again.