# GLUT animation with glutPostRedisplay

Tags: opengl, glut

Is there any difference between calling glutPostRedisplay() at the end of my display function and using an idle function callback that does nothing but call my display function?  I have seen both ways used in examples and cannot tell the difference by observation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A main loop generally looks like this:

1. Process and handle events

   calling stuff like `glutKeyboardFunc`/`glutMouseFunc`.
2. Advance/update 3D state (physics/animation etc)

   typically in `glutIdleFunc`
3. Re-draw the scene if needed

   use `glutDisplayFunc`

`glutPostRedisplay` simply sets a flag, that tells glut to call the display callback on the next loop iteration. It doesn't actually call display [<sup>[1]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26339036/pausing-in-opengl-successively) [<sup>[2]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30451058/why-is-glutpostredisplay-and-sleep-function-is-not-working-in-this-code/30454812#30454812).

If you have a game, which always updates every frame this might not be that useful. Maybe if you're alt-tabbed or dragging the window you don't need to be calling display. Or you might be frame limiting by dropping frames (although I'd suggest [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19677856/1888983)).

```
void idle()
{
    ...
    animatedThing.value += deltaTime
    glutPostRedisplay(); //scene is always changing. always call display
}
```

Having a "dirty" flag becomes more useful when you don't need to re-render continuously. Maybe in something like a 3D modelling package where there isn't any animation and you only move the camera occasionally. Or a GUI where you only need to update when you hover and click on stuff.

```
void mousedown(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    if (clickedGUI(x, y))
        glutPostRedisplay();
}

void idle()
{
    ...
    if (myKeys[MOVE_VIEW_FORWARD])
    {
        view.z -= deltaTime;
        glutPostRedisplay();
    }
}
```

Anyway, **to answer your question**, no, there's probably not much difference. However...

1. I'd put the `glutPostRedisplay` in `idle` as above. Calling from within `display` works but gives up some control you might want later. It's essentially this:

   ```
   bool shouldDraw = true;
   while (1)
   {
       // check events, input etc

       // idle/update state

       if (shouldDraw)
       {
           shouldDraw = false;
           // draw
           shouldDraw = true;
       }
   }
   ```
2. I also wouldn't call `display` from `idle` from a design perspective as it removes some control from glut. For example if there's a case where glut needs to override the post-redisplay (not that I know of one) it won't be able to.

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  I actually use GLUT more for sketching out animated  scenes so I am interested in the most-minimal form of a graphics program.  For now, that is just displayFunc and keyboardFunc.  I also use CGLSetParameter(kCGLCPSwapInterval) to lock rendering to 60Hz on the vsync.  I appreciate reading about other, more elaborate uses of GLUT though!